# Reading boolean correctly from Postgres by PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

### The main problem of this thread is moved to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314869/to-have-boolean-type-in-postgres-for-php) about boolean datatype in PHP / Postgres.

The problem is the **conversion of `t` and `f` to `true` and `false`, since  Postgres stores `true` and `false` as such.**

---

**How can you use the variable `a_moderator` in SESSION?**

I fetch the value of the variable `a_moderator` by

## #1 code of how I get the variable

```
    $result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "moderator_check_query", 
        "SELECT a_moderator 
        FROM users
        WHERE email = $1;"
    );
    $a_moderator = pg_execute($dbconn, "moderator_check_query", array($_SESSION['login']['email']));

    $rows = pg_fetch_all ( $a_moderator );
  
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
       $_SESSION['login']['a_moderator'] = $row['a_moderator'];
    }
```

I use it unsuccessfully by

## #2 code of how I use the variable unsuccessfully

```
if ( $_SESSION['login']['a_moderator'] == 't' ) {
   // do this
}
```

I also ran unsuccessufully the values such as `true` in the place of `t`.
The variable in the SESSION has the value `f` such that

## #3 Output which tells me he value of the varibale

> ```
> Array ( [login] => Array ( 
>    [passhash_md5] => dd2f85814c35fd465c30b1472f5d3af8 
>    [email] => nthoaeuntht@Thnatuh.comn 
>    [logged_in] => 1 [user_id] => 13 
>    [username] => oeauoeh 
>    [a_moderator] => t ) 
> )
> ```

Comment: you're still not properly fetching the data from with pg_fetch_array. It needs the PGSQL_ASSOC flag.

Comment: davethegr8: You suggest me that it is best to use `pg_fetch_all` and then simply `foreach` to read the data.

Comment: davethegr8: I fixed the problem with `pg_fethch_array`. I have still the same problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Select boolean field from postgre as ::int and in php cast to bool.

```
 "SELECT a_moderator::int 
        FROM users
        WHERE email = $1;"
```

> $isModerator = (bool)$row['a_moderator'];

Comment: Alternately, you can skip the cast in postgres, and do the conversion in PHP: `$isModerator=($row['a_moderator'] === 't');`

Comment: @Frank Farmer, you didn't got idea of question. Idea is to make code cross-platform between database extensions php_mysql, php_pgsql, php_sqlite and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but here's an example demonstrating that pg_*() functions do in fact return the postgres boolean true value as the PHP string 't':

```
[example]$ cat scratch.php 
<?php
//connect to the database...
require_once 'db_connect.php';

//query
$rows = pg_fetch_all(pg_query('SELECT TRUE::bool AS true'));
//dump returned array, and test with type-safe identity comparator
var_dump($rows, $rows[0]['true'] === 't');

[example]$ php scratch.php 
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["true"]=>
    string(1) "t"
  }
}
bool(true)
[example]$
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is the main point of your answer. I opened this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314869/to-have-boolean-type-in-postgres-for-php to solve the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function in postgres to export boolean to PHP readable boolean:

You just use it this way:

```
SELECT php_bool(columna) from
table
```

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION php_bool(boolean)
RETURNS numeric LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

  IF $1 = true THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END
$BODY$
```

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
if ( $_SESSION['login']['a_moderator'] ) {
  // do this
}
```

It is a boolean, not a string.

Comment: No, postgres booleans are returned in string form (as evidenced by the 't' in his print_r() output).  Try it.  I promise, pg_* never returns boolean row values as actual PHP booleans.