# To have boolean type in Postgres for PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, boolean

I can't believe that the [following statement](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29213&edit=1) seems to be still true

```
So, I switched to integers and 0 or 1 works fine, but it is
stupid, that the database system has boolean variables of a smaller
size, but I should use integers for boolean values!
```

**How do you use boolean datatype with Postgres / PHP?**

In other words,

**Is the only way to use 1 for true and 0 for false in getting the kind of the boolean datatype?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 1 and 0 is a very sensible and portable way to represent boolean values. Any difference in size between and int and a native boolean type is really going to make little or no difference to your application's performance, or the KB size of your database.

Comment: Your answer suggests me that I need to change every datatype `BOOLEAN` in my SQL queries to `INTEGER`. It is strange that the `BOOLEAN` is made string by postgres after running the queries.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you change anything. Maybe out of habit or personal preference, I tend to use 0 & 1s to represent booleans. If that is already working for you, don't spend too much time thinking about it.

Comment: Figures are easy. Let's use them :)

Comment: Mysql actually uses 0 and 1 in a tinyint(1) when you define a boolean datatype.