# checking for boolean true / false result in postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, lua

I am running the following sql query in my web app:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT id
FROM user
WHERE membership=1244)
```

i was expecting **true** (boolean data) as the result but I'm getting 't' or 'f' for false. 
How do I get it to return to my lua code a standard boolean?

I found the following post:

[Reading boolean correctly from Postgres by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314489/reading-boolean-correctly-from-postgres-by-php)

And so I tried to change my code to something like this:

```
SELECT EXISTS ::int (
SELECT id
FROM user
WHERE membership=1244)
```

or

```
SELECT ::INT (SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT id
FROM user
WHERE membership=1244))
```

But I'm getting a syntax error.
Can you tell the best way to handle this? Should I be casting the resulting 't' to a boolean somehow?  or is there a way to tell postgresql to return true / false instead of 't'/'f'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are so close

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM user WHERE membership=1244)::int
```

Comment: In Postgres 9.1.9, it works fine.  See the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bfe1e/2
Also, a 0 or 1 for PHP works as boolean

Comment: No problem.  You gave me an excuse to use sqlfiddle. Which I just learned about today, so I'm excited.  :)

Answer (score 7):

Your first query do indeed return a boolean. A `t` is shown as the returned value of the query

```
select exists (select 1);
 exists 
--------
 t
```

But if you check its type it is a boolean:

```
select pg_typeof(exists (select 1));
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 boolean
```

You will have to check with the lua's postgresql driver manual how to properly handle it.

Answer (score 5):

Try it with `CASE`

```
select       
  (case when exists (SELECT id FROM user WHERE membership = 1244)
    then 1 
    else 0 
  end) as column;
```

[my test fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2c2a4/9)

Answer (score 0):

Your initial query is fine by itself:

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE membership=1244
```

You just need to check if it returns a row or not.